# accessing objects outside of function inner scope in event call, and when do objects get cleaned up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks, typescript

I'm trying to create a utility method which will attach to the `$destroy` event of the `$scope$` of AngularJS, so  that it automatically cleans up the handler and avoid memory leaks.  Below is some sample code for this utility method called `attachEventToRootscopeAndRegisterUnbind()`, and is in TypeScript however should be quite similar to JavaScript.

```
class EventToUnRegister {
    public $scope: ng.IScope;
    public unbindHandler: Function;
    public eventName: string;
    public logger: Core.ILog;

    public onScopeDestroy() {
        this.logger.debug("EventToUnRegister:onScopeDestroy",`Scope destroyed, unbinding event '${this.eventName}'`);
        this.unbindHandler();

        //remove references
        this.logger = null;
        this.unbindHandler = null;
        this.$scope = null;
        this.eventName = null;


    }

}

    attachEventToRootscopeAndRegisterUnbind($scope: ng.IScope, eventName: string, listener: (event: angular.IAngularEvent, ...args: any[]) => any) {
        var eventToUnRegister = new EventToUnRegister();
        eventToUnRegister.$scope = $scope;
        eventToUnRegister.logger = this.logger;
        eventToUnRegister.unbindHandler = this.$rootScope.$on(eventName, listener);
        eventToUnRegister.eventName = eventName;
        $scope.$on("$destroy", () => {
            eventToUnRegister.onScopeDestroy();  //<-- IS IT AN ISSUE TO ACCESS THIS HERE?
            eventToUnRegister = null; //remove reference to make sure it is cleaned up
        });
    }
```

My issues are:

1. Are there any issues with accessing `eventToUnRegister` from the `$scope.$on` event handler?
2. Would there still be any form of memory leaks this way?

The original issue is that from a controller you attach to an event on the `$rootscope` for any reason.  Ideally, this is not done but sometimes it is needed. Then, since `$rootscope` never is destroyed, the controller will live on forever due to the event.  I'm trying to create this utility method to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks perfectly valid to me and as long as there is no chain of related events fired within the `$destroy` I don't see any problem. Besides you don't *need* to nullify everything so explicitly. If the reference to the containing object is out of scope (and none of it's child properties have somehow a reference back), the object is garbage collected.

Comment: What about accessing the variable `eventToUnRegister` declared outside of the scope of the event handler?  Is that an issue?  Is the value copied for each call, such that each subsequent call to the method `attachEventToRootscopeAndRegisterUnbind` have its own value of `eventToUnRegister`?

Comment: @KarlCassar: yes, each call of `attachEventTo...` has it's own instance of that `EventToUnRegister` object. JavaScript variables are scoped to the containing function. In your case the object instance is referenced via a so called _closure_ in the `$scope.$on('$destroy')` handler. Until that handler is (garbage) collected the object will live. After the `$destroy` event has been fired, angular will clean the scope, which will clean your event handler and thus the object instance.